# Karate- Gatling: Not able to run scenarios based on tags

Tags: karate

I am using karate framework for API testing. I am using existing feature files to do performance testing using Gatling.
I have feature file with 3 scenarios tagged @CO, @SRI and @SDP.
I am able to execute the scenario tagged @CO with the below lines in simulation file.

```
 val RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod = scenario("RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod").exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/abc/ipf/features/Examples/CustomerAccountService/RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod.feature@CO"))
```

If I update the above lines like this, I am getting error

```
val RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod = scenario("RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod").exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/singtel/ipf/features/Examples/CustomerAccountService/RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod.feature", "@CO"))
```

Listed below is my simulation file which throws error.

```
import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class CustomerAccountSimulation extends Simulation {

  val duration= 30 seconds
  val users = 2
  
   val apis = karateProtocol(
  )

  apis.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name") 
  
  val RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod = scenario("RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod").exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/abc/ipf/features/Examples/CustomerAccountService/RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod.feature", "@CO"))

  setUp(
    RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(users) during (duration))
  ).protocols(apis)
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
    15:22:26.159 [main] INFO  io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - Compiling 1 Scala source and 1 Java source to C:\Sudha\WP\customer-account-management-performance-testing\target\test-classes ...
15:22:28.179 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - C:\Sudha\WP\customer-account-management-performance-testing\src\test\java\com\abc\ipf\features\Examples\CustomerAccountService\CustomerAccountSimulation.scala:17:199: too many arguments (2) for method karateFeature: (name: String)com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateActionBuilder
  val RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod = scenario("RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod").exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/abc/ipf/features/Examples/CustomerAccountService/RetrieveBillDeliveryMethod.feature", "@CO"))
                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
15:22:28.250 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - one error found
15:22:28.252 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed
sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: null
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:242)
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:111)
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:90)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:133)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:116)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:307)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:307)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:106)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:87)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:116)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:63)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:89)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:134)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:80)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:67)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:311)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:269)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:159)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:238)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:69)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.doCompile(ZincCompiler.scala:210)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.delayedEndpoint$io$gatling$compiler$ZincCompiler$1(ZincCompiler.scala:215)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$delayedInit$body.apply(ZincCompiler.scala:39)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.main(ZincCompiler.scala:39)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler.main(ZincCompiler.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  15.854 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-07T15:22:28+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:3.0.4:test (default-cli) on project customer-account-management-performance-testing: Gatling failed.: Simulations compilation failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Please note my requirement is to run scenarios tagged @CO and @SRI. In this I am trying to run 1 scenario first.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: most likely this is the solution: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/404#issuecomment-417630286 - otherwise please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue